# How to work with generic date format

Tags: c#, datetime

i have C# program that work with access database. (i have datetime field in access - Short Date)
How to make sure that the program will not crash with the wrong date format ?

for example:
in my computer the date in this format: dd/MM/yyyy
and if i run my program on computer that has this format: MM/dd/yyyy
the program will crash or will show me abnormal result

is there any generic solution ?
can i get any C# code for this ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Validate your date prior to parsing using `DateTime.TryParse` e.g.

```
string myDate = "01/30/1970";
DateTime validDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(myDate, out validDate))
{
   // Good date, now stored in validDate
}
else
{
   // Handle/Cleanup bad date.            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to worry about this if you using System.DateTime.  Access and .Net will store the date as a numeric value.  On the front end side, you can format this however you like.  DateTime can take care of localization issues for you so you don't need to do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

```
private DateTime ParseDate(string date)
{
    DateTime convertedDate;

    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "ddMMyyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"),
         DateTimeStyles.None, out convertedDate))

        throw new FormatException(string.Format("Unable to format date:{0}", date));

    return convertedDate;

}
```